# Where can we find all the app setting for Azure App Services

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Where can we find list of app settings for azure app services for example there is

WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE, WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE. What are all the other WEBSITE_....options available.

Answer (score 0):

The options available are similar to those you'd put into `Web.config`, etc.

[See Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common)

Answer (score 0):

[The API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2019-08-01/sites) will list out all the available to those in the App Service though I'm not sure if your asking about these or specific web.config settings as another post answered.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

Configuration > Application Settings. Then you will find the app settings.

[image]